# Kodein factory bindings is throwing NotFoundException

Tags: kotlin, kodein

I don't know if this is a bug or I'm just doing it wrong. I see nothing in the documentation that says that kodein factory bindings should be called in any way other than this:

```
class KodeinConfidenceTest {
    @Test
    fun testThatKodeinWorks() {
        val kodein = Kodein {
            bind<Dice>() with factory { sides: Int -> RandomDice(sides) }
        }
        val d:Dice = kodein.instance(5)
    }
}
open class Dice
data class RandomDice(val sides:Int) : Dice()
```

...but this causes a NotFoundException

```
com.github.salomonbrys.kodein.Kodein$NotFoundException: No provider found for bind<Dice>("5") with ? { ? }
Registered in Kodein:
    bind<Dice>() with factory { Int -> RandomDice }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never write `kodein.instance(5)`, you should write `kodein.instance(tag = 5)`

Now you see your error. You are setting the tag (which differentiates bindings), not the argument to the factory.

In Kodein 4, the syntax is either `kodein.with(5).instance()` or `kodein.factory<Int, Dice>().invoke(5)`

I am currently developping Kodein 5 (no release schdule yet), in which this syntax will be changed to `kodein.instance(arg = 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me in Kodein 5 (5.3.0). The below did.

```
class Die(val sides: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val kodein = Kodein {
    bind<Die>() with factory { sides: Int -> Die(sides) }
  }
  val die: Die by kodein.instance { 20 }
  println("Sides ${die.sides}")
}
```